# TSQL or SQL dynamic WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables here...

> 1. GroupTable: uid, Level1, Level2, WhereClause
> 2. MainTable: uid, Name

I need to create something that allows me to use the WhereClause field as the actual WHERE clause for my query.

I.E.

```
select *
from MainTable
inner join GroupTable on GroupTable.uid=MainTable.uid
where {WhereClause}
```

In other words, something that will evaluate that WhereClause field as actual SQL. WhereClause might equal 'Field in (1,2,3)' or similar. I'm not a fan of doing that, but it's not currently practical to rewrite the process if at all possible. Hoping someone might point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: You need dynamic SQL via sp_executeSQL or EXEC()

Comment: http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html

Comment: What if first one have "field in (1,2,3)" and second one "field in (3,4,5)", another row in groupTable has "field not in (1,2,3,4,5)" ... and so on. With dynamic sql you would be doing one by one per row. Depending on your actual need, the frontend you are using, getting the whole tables to local and doing the filtering in your frontend might be a viable solution (ie: if grouptable and maintable are not large, a language like VFP would do this like a piece of cake).

Comment: Have you met [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)? You may want to study up on _SQL injection_.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with using dynamic sql and then executing the dynamically created sql string.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want but,

You can use dynamically like this, if you want:

```
DECLARE @where NVARCHAR(500) = ''

SET @where = ' userid =  3 '


EXEC (  ' SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE  ' + @where )

SET @where = ' userid IN (2,3,4) '

EXEC (  ' SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE  ' + @where )

-- Or you can also use other typo things.
```

If you explain exactly what you need, i might help.

Hope it helps, anyways. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
SELECT 'select * FROM mainTable
        inner join GroupTable on GroupTable.uid=MainTable.uid
        where ' + t.whereClause
FROM GroupTable
```

Which will produce your desired queries.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an excellent example of using dynamic sql, specifically with a dynamic where clause, the majority of it is this:

```
DECLARE @SQL varchar(1000)

SET @SQL = 'SELECT Cus_Name, Cus_City, Cus_Country FROM Customers '

IF @Cus_Name IS NOT NULL OR @Cus_City IS NOT NULL OR _
    @Cus_Country IS NOT NULL
 SET @SQL = @SQL + 'WHERE '

IF @Cus_Name IS NOT NULL
 SET @SQL = @SQL + 'Cus_Name = ' + @Cus_Name
...
EXEC(@SQL)
```

[SQL Team](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/implementing-a-dynamic-where-clause)